# Adding '...' in UITextView through Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uitextview, xcode7

I added a `UITextView` in a `UITableViewCell` content view through Interface Builder.
Then, I wanted to put three dots '...' as a text.

When I run the app in debug mode (simulated device or not), the Debug Session shows :

- 100% CPU occupation,
- no log output,
- no thread information.

My breakpoint is situated in `viewDidLoad`.

Thread1 is in a infinite loop, my breakpoint is never hit and I couldn't find where it happens through Instrument profiling.

In the other cases (empty text, random characters...), it runs as usually.
Later on, I try with one, two dots => KO...

Does it happen to you ?

My conf :
Swift 2.1, Xcode version 7.1 (7B91b), OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)

IBOutlet :

```
class SubscriptionViewController: UITableViewController, UITextViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var myName: UITextView!
```

Screenshots :
[image: IB screenshot]

[image: IBOutlet]

While running with these three dots :
[image: CPU occupation rate at 100%]

I launch profiling....nothing...
[image]

If I do the same operation with empty text :
[image]

No problem !

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I try it and have same problem with one dot and three dots:) It's looks like  it is a problem associated with special characters, because if you change `Text` type form `Plain` to `Attributed` this problem goes away

Comment: @alex_p bingo!. If you post it as an answer, I will give you some more points ... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like it is a problem associated with special characters.
If you change `Text` type in `Attributes Inspector` form `Plain` to `Attributed` this problem goes away.